# How to restrict user to see his comments only and admin can see everyone comments?

Tags: wp-admin

i was trying to achieve this how can i restrict user to see his comments only along with admin replies and admin can see everyone comments?

Any suggestion with code would be helpful as i am new to wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

[Semi-Private Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/semi-private-comments/).just install this plugin.This plugin masks comments so that a user can only see comments written by himself or by an admin. Admins can see all comments.

Comment: is there any way without installing plugin...

Comment: @kiran you are asking too much ... There is no way a vanilla Wordpress install can do what you ask.

Answer (score -2):

put this code in wp-admin/edit-comments.php

```
function myplugin_get_comment_list_by_user($clauses) {
    if (is_admin()) {
        global $user_ID, $wpdb;
        $clauses['join'] = ", wp_posts";
        $clauses['where'] .= " AND wp_posts.post_author = ".$user_ID." AND wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID";
    };
    return $clauses;
};
// ensure that editors and admins can moderate everything
if(!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) {
add_filter('comments_clauses', 'myplugin_get_comment_list_by_user');
}
```

Comment: Editing core admin files is *bad practice* and absolutely *not* recommended. Besides that, please add an explanation to your answer.